# Render Failure - Image is smokey

Tags: rendering

[image]
I am new to using blender and I am working on rendering a scene that uses portal lighting, but I am having some render issues and I don't know why. Is there anything I can try to fix this issue?

Denoising didn't seem to make a difference on the picture cloudiness one way or another. Adding more samples helped a lot, but I still have that issue some.[image]

Here's a link to my blender file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uNfl7msr-o_v0AR5WSfbMFfdvP_zo2Ly/view?usp=sharing

Thanks everyone, the advice was very helpful! For anyone else having this problem, try the advice below and primarily lower the number of your light sources in the scene.

Comment: Looks like denoising or clamping to me

Comment: Try increasing the samples

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Sampling helped some, but it didn't fix the problem. What else could I try?

Comment: Hi Trent, could You provide us a .blend file please?

Comment: Heres a google drive link to the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uNfl7msr-o_v0AR5WSfbMFfdvP_zo2Ly/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, in the archive you've sent i haven't found any portals.. to set them properly you shoud get an area lamp and not a sun one.

like this:[image: example1]

second, i recommend you to reduce the light bounces, its better for performance and i think it may help with some of the noise:

[image: example2]

the denoiser effect may be too strong, i'd leave it in the default settings, besides 8 radius costs a lot of performance..

A big part of the problem can be because there is too many light sources.. i don't know how you could fix this.. but from what i already said im pretty sure you'll get better results

Comment: Thank you. I forgot I changed my portals to sun lights. I thought the portals were the issue at first. 

Ill definitely try what you suggested. I also change my material properties and that has helped too.